# Flutter webview resuming the state

Tags: flutter

Hi I have one button in my home screen when clicking that button..it will open a new page with webview widget.(ex.webview widget initial URL is google,so it will open google.com).After that I am doing some interaction with that webpage,then Clicking back button will take me to home screen.If I click the button now,I want to open webview with resume interaction.(ex. I click on that button and it takes me google then I search for 'computer' in Google and it shows me the results.now clicking back button will take me home screen.again now I click on home screen button it will have to open webview with computer searched results).any idea?.......oh.  And I found out this one method  OnUrlChanged.listen()...but I don't know where to put it exactly??

Answer (score 0):

**Declaring variables**

```
final flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
String oldUrl;
```

...

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
oldUrl = url;} //You might have to use async here
.....
```

...

**In Your WebView Class**

```
return SafeArea(
          child: WebviewScaffold(
            url: oldURl==null? "www.google.com" : oldUrl ))
```

I assume you'll have a `MaterialPageRoute` to navigate to `Webview` from your button.
You can create the `class` with a parameter for url, and pass `oldUrl` or "google.com" as a parameter in it accordingly.